# Do the Clojure Inspector (inspect) ui buttons do anything?

Tags: clojure, inspect

Clojure comes with some basic ui apps that let you [inspect](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.inspector-api.html) objects.  The generic "inspect" ui has buttons on the top for List, Table, Bean, Line, Bar, Prev, Next, etc but as far as I can tell they don't do anything.  I looked at the source and they seem functionless from the [code](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/76e7c4317dc3eac80c4908ac5e5fb885e302b2a4/src/clj/clojure/inspector.clj#L148) as far as I can tell.  Am I crazy?

```
(use 'clojure.inspector)
(inspect (System/getProperties))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm ... I never use clojure.inspector, but as far as I can tell from taking a glimpse at the source those buttons really seem to do nothing.